# Justified text with usepackage typewriter

Tags: luatex, typewriter

The text when using usepackage `typewriter` is not justified. Is there a way to do that?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}    
\usepackage{lipsum}    
\providecommand\ttgreyone{0.1}
\providecommand\ttgreytwo{0.1}
\providecommand\ttrotatebold{3}
\providecommand\ttdownbold{20000}
\providecommand\ttrightbold{35000}
\providecommand\ttdownshifttwo{20000}
\providecommand\ttrotatenormal{3}
\providecommand\ttrightnormal{20000}
\providecommand\ttdownnormal{20000}    
\usepackage{typewriter}       
\begin{document}    
\lipsum[1- 3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: I don't think manual typewriters would "justify" unless the typist was expert at kerning the paper (I had much problems with this when using them for creating drawings with borders) Why do you need to distort the emulation ? What seems to be missing is valid hyphenation for your languages Certainly Latin typewriting is not one of them

Comment: The entire purpose of the `typewriter` package is to mimic the "look" of a page of text produced by, you guessed it, an old-fashioned typewriter. You know, the machine where you'd feed a page at a time, and when you'd come to the end of a physical line of text, you'd have to manually advance to the next line, etc. And if the typewriter wasn't high-end, letters would not all be lined up cleanly, and letters would not all have equal "weight" (darkness, ink). If you do not want this "typewriter look", you shouldn't be using the `typewriter` package.